# android list contents notifications

Tags: android

how to calculate total number of items in a listbox and display in a text box?

I want to dynamically add the number of items in the list and display in front of the heading in brackets and also in front of its image like a notification showing the pending requests

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myJList.getModel().getSize();
```

to get items in list box. and simply set it as text of your text box.

replace `myJList` with your list.